React-markdown newline + list not working nicely together
I'm using react markdown. I've seen issues with the newline not working and you either have to use a plugin or basically do replace(/\n\n/g, '&nbsp;\n')
The issue is, this will not work nicely with * lists. Here is an example
import React from "react";
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";
import remarkSubSuper from "remark-sub-super";

export default function App() {
  const input =
    "est1\n\n* test2\n\ntest3\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\ntest4\n\nas\n\nasdasdasd";
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ReactMarkdown source={input} plugins={[remarkSubSuper]} />
    </div>
  );
}

If I render this as is, newlines are not respected, but list works just fine. If I now replace input with input.replace(/\n\n/g, '&nbsp;\n') there are now new lines, however, if you inspect the elements, everything after * test2 has been moved inside the li
Image below is with input.replace(/\n\n/g, '&nbsp;\n')

Image below s original input only

What's going on? Here a link to play with it: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-markdown-playground-3wjpx
